# Migrate Asp.Net Profile Provider to Work in MVC (extending not working)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am trying to update an Asp.Net web forms website to using MVC 5. There is a shopping cart component that extends the profile provider. This xml located in the web.config appears to auto generate code in the old website project that provides a shopping cart property *but does nothing in the mvc version*:

```
   <!-- Profile provider -->
    <profile defaultProvider="SQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SQLProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <!-- Define our shopping cart which is contained in customerManager and serialized as binary -->
        <add name="ShoppingCart" allowAnonymous="true" type="customerManager.ShoppingCart, customerManager" serializeAs="Binary"></add>
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

Hence the following code fails:

```
Profile.ShoppingCart.AddItem(1500);
```

**Error 3   'System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase' does not contain a definition for 'ShoppingCart' and no extension method 'ShoppingCart' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\VirtualWeb2\VirtualWeb2\Controllers\AccountController.cs 92  29  VirtualWeb2**

The original code for the shopping cart is in a stand alone DLL although I can get to the source if I really need to. I'd prefer to handle it through configuration if this is possible.

I've looked at many posts online and can't find anything that covers my same scenario. **Any idea why this "ShoppingCart" property does not autogenerate when building the mvc project but works in the asp net web forms website?**

Comment: Just to be clear, are the MVC project and the ASP.NET project the same VS project, or are they separate projects?

Comment: They are separate. I created a whole new project and I am trying to port each piece over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KingOfHypocrites answer (from comment):**

```
public static ShoppingCart GetCart(this Controller c) 
{ 
    var cart = c.Profile["ShoppingCart"]; 
    return (customerManager.ShoppingCart)cart; 
}
```

Comment: I think you are on right track. It looks like web application projects don't do the build automatically. I found more info here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class

Comment: Yea, but I thought of another stumbling block. Profile providers are based on a cookie, and 2 web sites cannot share a cookie unless they are in the same domain.

Comment: it is only one website, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Doing this fixed my problem:         public static ShoppingCart GetCart(this Controller c)
        {
            var cart = c.Profile["ShoppingCart"];
            return (customerManager.ShoppingCart)cart;
        }

Comment: Good find. Ironically, that is what I did in my web project because I had to do some customization to the profile save method, but I had no idea it was also the solution to this problem.

Comment: I tried the solution in the article I posted but it kept resetting the profile, so i decided just to do the extension method although not as elegant. Far as I know the solution in the article (if I could get it working) and the custom build you posted are the only other ways to do it. I only have one custom property so the extension method gets the job done. Thanks for the help :)